# How to override existing methods by custom module in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

Below method is existing in `account.move.line`

```
def _default_get_move_form_hook(self, cursor, user, data):
    data = super(account_move_line, self)._default_get_move_form_hook(cursor, user, data)
    if data.has_key('analytics_id'):
        del(data['analytics_id'])
    return data
```

I want to remove its functionality by override it in my custom module.
Can anyone please tell me, how can I do it.
I am trying below code:

```
@api.multi
def _default_get_move_form_hook(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    if self.pool['res.users'].has_group(cr, uid, 'base.group_erp_manager'):
        res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','LAL')], context=context)
        return res and res[0] or False
    elif self.pool['res.users'].has_group(cr, uid, 'purchase.group_purchase_user'):
        res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','SAS')], context=context)
        return res and res[0] or False
```

Comment: Is this what you have written in your code? Do you want to totally change the functionality of that method?

Comment: Just remove super method calling then it will never going to look at the base method.

Comment: I want to remove its functionality totally... but by custom code...

Comment: This code is existing in odoo module `account_analytic _plan` I want to remove its functionality by custom code.

Answer (score 1):

in you new module that inherit from the account.move.line 
dont use the new api then use the old one every method need 4 argument

```
def _default_get_move_form_hook(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    #put you custom code here
```

or just redifine the method with same name this should overrid it

Comment: I have already try  it but it is giving me this error `TypeError: _default_get_move_form_hook() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: I am trying it   `@api.multi def  _default_get_move_form_hook(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        if self.pool['res.users'].has_group(cr, uid, 'base.group_erp_manager'):
            res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','LAL')], context=context)
            return res and res[0] or False
        elif self.pool['res.users'].has_group(cr, uid, 'purchase.group_purchase_user'):
            res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','SAS')], context=context)
            return res and res[0] or False`

Comment: this erreur is because of the old api did you use the decorater  @api.mutli  if yes than remove it and put all argument

Comment: if I remove it then it gives me this error. `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'has_key'`

Comment: that means that you overrid it  try to find what peace of code is given you this erreur try comments until you find the erreur

Comment: is the erreur comes from this method or the original method!!

Comment: i think the erreur comes from this line :  res and res[0] or False

Comment: res is a RecordSet what you want to return execalty

Comment: i want to set default value `    _defaults = {
        'analytics_id': _default_get_move_form_hook,
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118009/discussion-between-charif-and-tahir-noor).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove its functionality by override it in your custom module.

You need to maintain the signature of method same as it is in original so

```
def _default_get_move_form_hook(self, cr, uid, data):
```

instead of

```
def _default_get_move_form_hook(self, cr, uid, context=None):
```

Later you need to make sure that your method should get called instead of original method, how ? follow the steps..

- you need to make sure that you are not making a super call to original method.
  and also
- search for the original method is being called from the module or part of odoo,
- replace the method getting called from original class in original module by your class in your module

try this .. .

Thanks!

### **Update:**

you need to make sure that the method you are going to override, is using the same Odoo version style,

> All OpernERP v7 methods can't accepts odoo v8 style, so I have updated my answer by removing  `@api.multi`
>
> Direct conversion of OpenERP V7 method -> Odoo V8 with decorator doesn't always guarantee to work as normal,
> so best practice is the class and method structure you need to make sure to be same as original

Answer (score 0):

To override it you can use:

```
@api.multi
def _default_get_move_form_hook(self):
    #Custom code
```

The expected returned value of this method is a dict, so make sure you return a dict.

`_default_get` returns `_default_get_move_form_hook` result:

```
def _default_get(...):   
    ...  
    data = self._default_get_move_form_hook(cr, uid, data)  
    return data
```

And `default_get` calls `default_get`:

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    data = self._default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
    for f in data.keys():
        if f not in fields:
            del data[f]
    return data
```